# Edid information

Tags: linux, xorg, monitors, edid

I want to gather the Edid information of the monitor.
I can get it from the `xorg.0.log` file when I run `X` with the `-logverbose` option.

But the problem is that If I switch the monitor (unplug the current monitor and then plug-in another monitor), then there is no way to get this information.

Is there any way to get the EDID dynamically (at runtime)?
Or any utility/tool which will inform me as soon as monitor is connected and disconnected?

I am using the LFS-6.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tool called [read-edid](http://polypux.org/projects/read-edid/) doing exactly what its name suggests.

Comment: yeah but it did not give it runtime. or to rephrase the Question "Is there any utility/tool to get the serial ID of monitor?"

Comment: It seems to depend on the driver of the card and on the monitor itself ... I have found [this discussion](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=250723) (the `/sys` investigation is the lowest you can get usually) and the [Wikipedia entry about EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) is really interesting.

Comment: get-edid from read-edid couldn't read my EDID info (perhaps get-edid is outdated?), but as Fussy Salsify mentions, the info is also exposed through `/sys`. And edid-decode from the same package still works fine. I documented how to access and decode the info at http://superuser.com/a/628042/20768

Answer (score 4):

Try **xrandr** --verbose. It shows the RAW edid information and lots of other useful information for all monitors connected to your computer.

Example output, with only the EDID section:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
(cut)
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff0030ae364000000000
        00130103801e1378eaef259458568a29
        24505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101018a25a02051841a303040
        360030be100000195e1fa02051841a30
        3040360030be100000190000000f0095
        0a32950a2816090030e47302000000fe
        004c503134315750332d544c413100ab
(cut)
```

With regards to your last question, **udev** can inform you and let you run commands when a monitor is connected. It's really easy to write bash scripts for udev events.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but I find xrandr very useful for automatically setting the monitor layout that I want whenever I plug or unplug external monitors at work or at home. You don't need monitor serial for this. The simplified output name works fine. Run xrandr to see the outputs (monitors) available.

I run this script to set my preferred layout:

```
#!/bin/bash 
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto
xrandr --output DP2 --auto --right-of LVDS1
```

LVDS1 being the name of the notebook monitor, DPS2 the external one.

Comment: @Yvus, The answer you are giving is the other face of what I told earlier ( Xorg --logverbose 6 ).  And, as far as, UDEV is concerned, UDEV do not recognized the current status of monitor ( I checked it on Debian lenny ).  If you have rules for the same, please share it.  Thanks.