# /sys/class/drm directory structure

Tags: linux, drivers, video

Who is responsible for creating the "/sys/class/drm" directory structure, more specifically the "/sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1" directory?

I am using kernel-2.6.38 and an nVidia card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DRM module is responsible for that subtree in SysFS. You can browse the source code for that in [`drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c`](http://kerneldox.net/d9/d9e/drm__sysfs_8c-source.html).

The subdirectories are per-connector, with a name of the form `card%d-%s` with `%d` replaced by an index (that I know nothing about) and `%s` replaced with the connector name.

Five files per device should show up:

- Connection status
- Enabled (or not)
- DPMS state
- Mode list
- EDID

For some devices, you'll get extra information for sub-connectors too.

Comment: I inserted the "drm" module, but I get the blank directory.

Comment: Yes, and? If you're using the proprietary nVidia driver, I don't believe it uses/supports (whatever the right term is) DRM. Not sure if the nouveau driver does.

Comment: I need this directory structure for another purpose. but to use it, I had to make it's presence on system.

Comment: If your driver doesn't use/support DRM, you won't get it.

Comment: My final intention is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/edid-information

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that if your card's driver doesn't talk to the Linux DRM subsystem, _you won't get that directory_.

Answer (score 1):

There has been some development since the last accepted answer, hence I'm creating a new answer.

As of v6.2.11 the source code responsible for this sysfs subtree is still [drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c) (working link).

The DRM driver itself may create 5 different entry types, based on hardware support. They are: `card%d`, `controlD%d`, `renderD%d`, `accel%d`, then for each card connector `card%d-%s`. The `%d` are device minor numbers, which should start at 0 for the cards then in matching 64 increments for `controlD`, `renderD` and `accel` respectively. There are no minors for the connectors, they are on their respective card's minor.

The `controlD` entries are backward-compatibility symlinks created by `create_compat_control_link()` in [drivers/gpu/drm/drm_drv.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_drv.c) and use the originally reserved minor number for `controlD`.

The connector name's format (the `%s` in `card%d-%s`) is `%s-%d`, where `%s` is a name from `struct drm_conn_prop_enum_list drm_connector_enum_list[]` in  [drivers/gpu/drm/drm_connector.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_connector.c) and `%d` is a connector index number starting from 1 (as a card may have more than one connector of the same type).

Finally, any driver can register its own devices here using `drm_class_device_register()` in [drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c).